# Pin icons to taskbar

Tags: nsis, taskbar

How can I pin the shortcut icons to windows 7 taskbar using NSIS installer?

I tried to place them in below location but it doesnt work well

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Comment: The user is supposed to be in control of which shortcuts are pinned. Imagine what the taskbar would look like if all applications did this! See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx

Comment: @Anders Ofcourse I will give a checkbox option at install time to user to decide whether to pin or not. Even placing desktop shortcut without permission is against compliance now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this plugin: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StdUtils_plug-in, Review **InvokeShellVerb** section documentation: http://muldersoft.com/docs/stdutils_readme.html

Comment: Yes, use `${StdUtils.Const.ShellVerb.UnpinFromStart}` to unpin.